Error occurred: contract creation code storage out of gas
I am trying to deploy a smart contract on the ethereum sepolia testnet in Remix IDE. But I'm getting the error "contract creation code storage out of gas". I do not understand the reason for this, since I have enough testnet ETH in my wallet, and I have only imported the necessary libraries.
Here is the full code:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract IssueCred is ERC20, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant DOCTOR_ROLE = keccak256("DOCTOR_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant PHARMACIST_ROLE = keccak256("PHARMACIST_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant GOVERNMENT_ROLE = keccak256("GOVERNMENT_ROLE");

    struct HealthCareProvider {
        string name;
        string licenseNumber;
        bool isVerified;
    }

    struct Prescription {
        address doctor;
        string drug;
        uint dosage;
        uint duration;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    mapping(address => HealthCareProvider) public providers;
    mapping(string => Prescription[]) private prescriptions;

    event ProviderRegistered(address indexed providerAddress, string name, string licenseNumber);
    event ProviderVerified(address indexed providerAddress);
    event PrescriptionIssued(address indexed doctor, string indexed patientID, string drug, uint dosage, uint duration);

    constructor() ERC20("AccountabilityToken", "PHARMA") {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(GOVERNMENT_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * (10 ** decimals()));
    }

    function registerProvider(
        address providerAddress,
        string calldata name,
        string calldata licenseNumber,
        bytes32 role
    ) external onlyRole(GOVERNMENT_ROLE) {
        require(role == DOCTOR_ROLE || role == PHARMACIST_ROLE, "Invalid role");

        providers[providerAddress] = HealthCareProvider({
            name: name,
            licenseNumber: licenseNumber,
            isVerified: false
        });
        emit ProviderRegistered(providerAddress, name, licenseNumber);
    }

    function verifyProvider(address providerAddress, bytes32 role) external onlyRole(GOVERNMENT_ROLE) {
        require(providers[providerAddress].isVerified == false, "Provider already verified");

        providers[providerAddress].isVerified = true;
        _grantRole(role, providerAddress);
        emit ProviderVerified(providerAddress);
    }

    function isProviderVerified(address providerAddress) external view returns (bool) {
        return providers[providerAddress].isVerified;
    }

    function issuePrescription(
        string calldata patientID,
        string calldata drug,
        uint dosage,
        uint duration
    ) external onlyRole(DOCTOR_ROLE) {
        prescriptions[patientID].push(Prescription({
            doctor: msg.sender,
            drug: drug,
            dosage: dosage,
            duration: duration,
            timestamp: block.timestamp
        }));
        emit PrescriptionIssued(msg.sender, patientID, drug, dosage, duration);
    }

    function getPrescriptions(string calldata patientID) external view returns (Prescription[] memory) {
        return prescriptions[patientID];
    }
}


I searched online and found that increasing the gas limit would help my case but no such thing happened. Additionally, I tried optimizing the code by replacing the lists I had made for registered providers and verified providers with events. Can anyone please tell me if my code is optimized or not?
